# Firebase data not loading after login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys i am new to firebase and i am trying to login into the existing user in my account and then trying to fetch data on database reference however i am unable to get snapshot please help and thanks in advance!

here is my code angular

```
var fou  = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.username, $scope.pswd).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                console.log(errorCode);
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorMessage);
            // ...
            });
            console.log(fou);
            $location.path('/main');
```

and in maincontroller

```
var Ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
console.log(starCountRef);
    Ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        $timeout(function() {

    jsondata = snapshot.val();
    console.log(jsondata); });
```

this is my rule in firebase live database

```
{"rules": {
".read": "auth == true",
".write": "auth == true" }}
```

Comment: what is the problem? what do you see in your console?

Comment: just these objects C {N: 0, na: undefined, s: C, ja: null, Pa: null…}

Comment: {u: Te, path: L, m: ee, Nc: false, then: undefined…}

Comment: This looks wrong: `auth == true`. You might want to try `auth != null`, which are the [default security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules).

Comment: That worked thanks Frank

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are fetching data correctly but you haven't written any data.

To write data, try:

```
var writeData = function (someContent) {

    Ref('data').set({
        content: someContent
    });

};

writeData('abc');
```